# Must I declare own wxFrame class?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm creating simple c++ application with user interface. I have written own classes with needed mechanics, and now I must display some of its components using wxWidgets. `MyApp` contains objects of that classes, but they are also needed in `MyFrame` when handling events. It would be much more comfortable without passing pointers to that objects to `MyFrame` and implement everything in `MyApp::OnInit` function. Is that possible?

```cpp
// should contain informations about game state, players, gameboard, etc
class MyApp : public wxApp {
    GameBoard gb;
    Player player;
    bool lightTheme;
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
```

```cpp
// should contain only window layout, button events, etc
class MyFrame : public wxFrame {
    GameBoard *gb;
    Player *player;
    bool *lightTheme;

    std::vector<wxStaticBitmap*> cardImages;
// some events here
    void displayImages(wxGridSizer*);
public:
    MyFrame(GameBoard*, Player*, bool*);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your title question, you don't have to declare `MyFrame` and can just create and directly use `wxFrame` and use `Bind()` to connect the different event handlers. In all but the simplest situations, it's typically *convenient* to have a `MyFrame` class centralizing the data and event handlers for the window, but it is not required by any means.

If you decide to keep everything in `MyApp` instead, you may find [wxGetApp()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.2/group__group__funcmacro__appinitterm.html#gac387a69e740a149f9888e4992a3a4c6c) useful for accessing it from various places in your code.